# Error in solution to a problem of matrix of "o's" and "x's" in C language. In this we need to count and identify adjacent elements

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Given a n × n checkerboard. Each cell of the board has either character 'x', or character 'o'. Is it true that each cell of the board has even number of adjacent cells with 'o'? Two cells of the board are adjacent if they share a side.

Input
The first line contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100). Then n lines follow containing the description of the checkerboard. Each of them contains n characters (either 'x' or 'o') without spaces.

Output
Print "YES" or "NO" (without the quotes) depending on the answer to the problem.

I have been pondering quite a while as to what I have done wrong, can someone please help me  point out the error in my logic in my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main () {

    int n,flag=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char arr[n][n];
    int arr_counter[n][n];

    for (int x=0;x<n;x++) {
        for (int y=0;y<n;y++) {
            arr_counter[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
        }

    }
    
   
    // corners
    // top left
    
    if(arr[1][0]=='o') {
        arr_counter[0][0] += 1;
    }
    if(arr[0][1] == 'o') {
        arr_counter[0][0] += 1;
    }
    
    // top right

    
    if(arr[0][n-2]=='o') {
        arr_counter[0][n-1] += 1;
    }
    if(arr[1][n-1] == 'o') {
        arr_counter[0][n-1] += 1;
    }
    
    // bottom left
   
    if(arr[n-2][0]=='o') {
        arr_counter[n-1][0] += 1;
    }
    if(arr[n-1][1] == 'o') {
        arr_counter[n-1][0] += 1;
    }            
    
    // bottom right  
    
    if(arr[n-2][n-1]=='o') {
        arr_counter[n-1][n-1] += 1;
    }
    if(arr[n-1][n-2] == 'o') {
        arr_counter[n-1][n-1] += 1;
    }            
    
            // edges
    for (int a=1;a<n;a++) {
        if(arr[0][a+1] == 'o') {
                arr_counter[0][a] += 1;
            } 
        if(arr[0][a-1] == 'o') {
                arr_counter[0][a] += 1;
            } 
        if(arr[1][a] == 'o') {
                arr_counter[0][a] += 1;
        }

    }

    
    for (int b=1;b<n;b++) {
        
        if(arr[b-1][0] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[b][0] += 1;
        }
        if(arr[b+1][0] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[b][0] += 1;
        }
        if(arr[b][1] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[b][0] += 1;
        }
    }
    
    for (int c=1;c<n;c++) {
         
        if(arr[c-1][n-1] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[c][n-1] += 1;
        }
        if(arr[c+1][n-1] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[c][n-1] += 1;
        }
        if(arr[c][n-2] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[c][n-1] += 1;
        }
    }
    
    for (int d=1;d<n;d++) {
         
        if(arr[n-1][d+1] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[n-1][d] += 1;
        }
        if(arr[n-1][d-1] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[n-1][d] += 1;
        }
        if(arr[n-2][d] == 'o') {
            arr_counter[n-1][d] += 1;
            }
        }
            
        //middle

    for (int s=1;s<n-1;s++) {
        for (int t=1;t<n-1;t++) {
            
            if(arr[s+1][t] == 'o') {
                arr_counter[s][t] += 1;
            } 
            if(arr[s-1][t] == 'o') {
                arr_counter[s][t] += 1;
            }
            if(arr[s][t+1] == 'o') {
                arr_counter[s][t] += 1;
            }
            if(arr[s][t-1] == 'o') {
                arr_counter[s][t] += 1;
            }
            
        }
    }

   




    for (int k=0;k<n;k++) {
        for (int l=0;l<n;l++) {
            if (arr_counter[k][l]%2 != 0) {
                flag = 1;
            } 
        }

    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("YES");
    } else if (flag == 1) {
        printf("NO");
    }
}

/*
Test Case 1
input
3
xxo
xox
oxx
output
YES
Test Case 2
input
4
xxxo
xoxo
oxox
xxxx
output
NO 





*/
```

Comment: What makes you think that your code is faulty? What is the error case?

Comment: Code is executing fine without error but not producing the desired output. Even test case 1 is showing NO instead of YES. So some problem in logic.

Comment: You did not test your input method. You are typing the test case with carriage returns, which the code accepts as characters. Fix that before you worry about counting neighbors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error is caused by a mundane bug having nothing to do with the central logic of the program.